# iMac Time Machine backup to Qnap external drive

Tags: backup, time-machine, imac

I can access the Time Machine backup files on Qnap external device which is shown in file station. It is named `Imacsparsebundle`.

I use the Qnap TS-932PX system as a backup and storage server for a mix of Mac, Windows and Xerox equipment.

When I open the folder it shows the following contents:

```
Mapped
Bands
Token
Lock
Info.Plst
Info.Bckp
Com.apple.Timemachine.Snapshothistory.Plst
Etc.
```

*but* when I open the mapped folder it only shows a list of file names such as:

```
FF
FFE
```

running along 500 files.

When opening the Bands folder it shows the same sequence as above.

But I thought the principle of Time Machine is that you can select the individual file/folder to restore?

If you then click on an item it then displays the contents encoded.

But if you cannot see it then what?

Or is this really a question for Qnap?

Comment: Timeshare is Time Machine I assume? Are you accessing your TM backups via the TM interface?

Comment: The sparse bundle needs to be mounted on macOS before you can browse the contents. You won't be able to view the backup via the QNAP tools. Once mounted it will be available to the Time Machine UI. The sparse bundle is a method to store a macOS filesystem, such as HFS+ or APFS, on a non Apple device. Time Machine will only use a macOS filesystem as a destination.

Comment: Many thanks for the info, I did not know that and I will give it a go